# Regex no MySQL para buscar determinados resultados de X tempo

Tags: mysql, regex, query

Eu tenho um campo na tabela definido como DATE e os dados são salvos neste campo da seguinte forma: ano-mês-dia hora:minuto:segundo

```
Exemplo: 2014/04/22 18:32:00
```

Eu preciso desenvolver uma consulta que me retorna apenas determinado ano/dia/mês.

Um esquema:

```
IR PARA -> TABELA -> E só pegar o resultados que o ano de 2014 -> 2014-xx-xx     xx: xx:xx
```

Onde X é um valor aleatório, ou seja, ele retorna qualquer valor para mim, pois é o ano de 2014

De uma maneira que eu posso fazer isso com o ano/mês/dia ..

Comment: Pus uma resposta que não usa regex, na verdade imagino que regex não traria nenhum benefício neste caso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Para datas completas:**

```
-- Se seu campo for DATE:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DATE(minhadata) = '2014-05-21';
-- Se seu campo for VARCHAR:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE LEFT(minhadata,10) = '2014/05/21';
```

**Para ano apenas:**

```
-- Se o campo for DATE:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE YEAR(minhadata) = '2014';
-- Se o campo for VARCHAR:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE LEFT(minhadata,4) = '2014';
```

**Para mês apenas:**

```
-- Se o campo for DATE:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE MONTH(minhadata) = '05';
-- Se o campo for VARCHAR:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE SUBSTR(minhadata, 6, 2) = '05';
```

**Para dia apenas:**:

```
-- Se o campo for DATE:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DAY(minhadata) = '23';
-- Se o campo for VARCHAR:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE SUBSTR(minhadata, 9, 2) = '23';
```

**Combinando as possibilidades acima**

Eis um exemplo de como obter os registros do dia 17 de todos os meses de 2013:

```
-- Se o campo for DATE:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE
   YEAR(minhadata) = '2013' AND
   DAY(minhadata) = '17';
-- Se o campo for VARCHAR:
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE
   LEFT(minhadata,4) = '2013' AND
   SUBSTR(minhadata, 9, 2) = '17';
```

> Notar que estou considerando a data `VARCHAR` no formato `AAAA/MM/DD`.
>   Para outros formatos, ajuste o `SUBSTR(campo,posicaoinicial,quantidade)` de acordo.

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Um campo do tipo DATE não grava data em nenhum formato, grava um número inteiro internamente, a conversão para "data" no momento do select depende do parâmetro de formato de data, para extrair o ANO por exemplo utilize FUNCTIONS do MySql como YEAR.

Comment: Sim, mas meu sistema guarda a data desta forma em um campo VARCHAR e eu preciso que seja assim, nao existe outras solucoes?

Comment: Usar tipos diferentes não é recomendado pois dá trabalho posteriores, sendo um campo do tipo CHAR use a FUNCTION SUBSTR.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr

Comment: Mas sua definição inicial era que o campo é do tipo DATE. Qual é o "type" do campo finalmente !?

Comment: Eu me referi que o nome do campo era DATE nao sua definicao, perdao.

Comment: DATE E DATA é palavra reservada, não se deve usar como nome de campo. use algo como CREATION_DATE ou DATA_DE_CRIACAO